# Running Solidity's keccak256 in python

Tags: keccak

I want to run Solidity`keccak256(abi.encodePacked(challenge_number, msg.sender, nonce))` where nonce is uint256, challenge_digest is bytes32, challenge_number bytes32, testTarget is uint.

What's the analog of this in python? I've already connected to the contract with my metamask account through Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Web3.solidityKeccak(abi_types, value)](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#Web3.solidityKeccak) should do the job

Examples:

```
Web3.solidityKeccak(['bool'], [True])
# HexBytes("0x5fe7f977e71dba2ea1a68e21057beebb9be2ac30c6410aa38d4f3fbe41dcffd2")

Web3.solidityKeccak(['uint8', 'uint8', 'uint8'], [97, 98, 99])
# HexBytes("0x4e03657aea45a94fc7d47ba826c8d667c0d1e6e33a64a036ec44f58fa12d6c45")

Web3.solidityKeccak(['uint8[]'], [[97, 98, 99]])
# HexBytes("0x233002c671295529bcc50b76a2ef2b0de2dac2d93945fca745255de1a9e4017e")

Web3.solidityKeccak(['address'], ["0x49EdDD3769c0712032808D86597B84ac5c2F5614"])
# HexBytes("0x2ff37b5607484cd4eecf6d13292e22bd6e5401eaffcc07e279583bc742c68882")

Web3.solidityKeccak(['address'], ["ethereumfoundation.eth"])
# HexBytes("0x913c99ea930c78868f1535d34cd705ab85929b2eaaf70fcd09677ecd6e5d75e9")
```

Comment: And anyone who wants to just get the string out of the `HexBytes`, you can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51610916/7520013